# Import Data in Excel from table(s) in a WebPage with pull down choices

Tags: excel, web, import

I need to import data table (with dates and prices) into excel from this page:

(see "Table" tab in the web page down below)

http://www.lbma.org.uk/pricing-and-statistics

You will notice that there is a pull down menu option; I need to import those choices into Excel.

When I use standard web import the table doesn't show and I cannot select the data.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code you will see the table is inside an iframe with src url: http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/table

That is where youre table is, so import that in Excel. Good luck